# Why Spring @Autowired inject another objecjt?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot v1.5.8.RELEASE.

I have defined a `WebSocketHandler` in which I am keeping list of sessions.
In another `@Component` I have autowired this handler to reach its sessions. However it is always zero-size (although the original is not). Could not I autowired the same, single one object? Why? Is not `@Component` singleton by default?

Here is the code:

**WebSocketHandler.java**

```
@Component
public class WebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    public CopyOnWriteArrayList<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<WebSocketSession>();

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        sessions.add(session);
        System.out.println("SIZE: "+ sessions.size()); // -> This grows as clients connected
    }

    public CopyOnWriteArrayList<WebSocketSession> getSessions() {
        return sessions;
    }
}
```

**MyComponent.java**

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    @Autowired
    WebSocketHandler wshandler;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=20000)
    public void mytask() {
        System.out.println(wshandler.sessions.size()); // THIS IS ALWAYS ZERO           
        // wshandler.getSessions().size() -> no difference
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you prove to yourself that `wshandler` is growing and shrinking when adding/removing sessions?

Comment: @Dovmo I am connecting to websocket using browser. Each time I connect, I see from prints that its size is growing and each time I close the browser it is disconnecting and the size is shrinking.

Comment: I'm also a little confused why your class is called `WebSocketHandler`; the [same name as the Spring interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/handler/TextWebSocketHandler.html)? I bet that you're autowiring in the [Spring interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/handler/TextWebSocketHandler.html) (see your imports), and not your own class with the same name! Either change your class name of your own SockerHandler or fix your import in your MyComponent!

Comment: @Dovmo ohh! I had not noticed that! I'll check it and tell the result. Thanks!

Comment: Now that I look at MyComponent again, though, it looks like you get access the getSessions method, which means you must be importing the right one. I would either way rename it to a different class.
Have you tried printing out your beans to see what's in your context?

Comment: @Dovmo Right. getSessions gave the same result. I didn't try it yet. The other thing that is suspicious is Scheduled. I do not know if Scheduled task is able to see the changes in autowired objects.

Comment: Nope, you are absolutely correct in assuming the autowired singleton should be accessible from the @Scheduled annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a dummy error.
In the configuration of WebSocketHandler, which I have copied directly from an example, I was already creating a handler.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler(), "/mywebsocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");     
    }
}
```

So, the fix was easy:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    MyWebSocketHandler wshandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(wshandler, "/mywebsocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");      
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Dovmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8415703/dovmo), I have also changed the name of class to MyWebSocketHandler as Spring already has WebSocketHandler.